# Why we should filter the correct user before calling method on it, if we can only use current_user.method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see usually people do something like this for checking the correct user, example :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  # ....
  # ....
  private
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

why we should do all this verification if we can simply do :

```
current_user.update(:user_params)
```

i think this way we are sure that we update only the current user information ! I don't know if first method is a habit we learned through tutorials or something else, but i want to know your opinion ?

Answer (score 0):

Current_user is provided by devise or any other authentication solution, not by rails.
Beside if you use current_user you could only update the logged in user, as you wrote.
If you ever have roles and admin users who should be able to edit other users too, you would need to find those users by id.
Technically current_user is loaded by providing the correct email and password upon singing in, while User.find finds the user by his id (obviously).
A better solution to make sure users could only update their own record(s) would be to use authorization eg CanCan.

To provide a more direct answer to your question: If you want to update the currently logged in user, updating it with current_user.update should be fine, because the current_user holds the same User record that you could access with User.find.
I think the reason why you do not see using current_user for that more is because using User.find is more general and maybe partially because people are lazy and just uses the generated controller code that the rails generator creates for them.

Comment: i know that current_user is not provided by rails but in the majority of time we create it in our project, my thinking is that current_user.update is sufficient if we want to update information of the logged in user